# PHP sessions not saving on page refresh or after going to another page

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, session, amazon-ec2, composer-php

My sessions are not saving on page refreshes or going to another page. This all started happening after updating all my composer files with `composer update` and upgrading my EC2 server from t2.nano to t2.micro. I'm not sure what caused it?

I've tried this code to see if my sessions were saving and IT IS saving:

```
if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!'; 
}
```

Here is how i'm testing my SESSION code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 'ok'; // 1st time loading the page works. I remove this line on the second refresh and the var_dump below does not show the session.

var_dump($_SESSION);
die();

?>
```

Comment: Did you check if the browser has a coolie?

Comment: @SimonMüller I've tried incognito and i've tried my mobile phone browser

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. I was working on my dev site with IP address but I had `session.cookie_secure = 1` which made it not work. I had to disable it so I just commented it out:

```
;session.cookie_secure = 1
```